# Why Rstudio is confused about the working directory

Tags: r, directory, r-markdown, rstudio

My Rstudio is acting up and being confused about the actual working directory, you can see in the embedded photo that in the console the directory is set to a specific folder, but when running the code it gives me an error that my file does not exist in the (wrong) directory. why is this happening and how can i fix it ?

[image: Console Screen]

Comment: R-markdown documents refer to the directory in which the Rmd file is saved in, NOT the location of your .Rproj file. If the csv file is in your Data folder, try `read_csv("../Data/Cyclistic12months.csv")`. `"../`" means "go up a folder".

Comment: @Phil thanks fill, will try this out. But what is confusing that this error came up suddenly, it was working normally before and then it just started showing up. i fixed it by setting up the directory manually in the code chunk, but i just want to understand why the console is set to a specific path while the program is looking for the file somewhere else, as shown in the screenshot it is contradictory

Comment: `directory is set to a specific folder` --> I don't see any of your code setting (via `setwd(..)`) or using a specific directory other than `.` (current, implied by the lack of path in your call to `read_csv`). Not knowing what you `set` (off-screen?) or what is inferred, I'm not sure how to help.

Comment: @admo7000 Without further information as to what your working directory is set to, and the organization of your folders, it's impossible to help.

Comment: I'm guessing the answer to your question is found here https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711843-Working-Directories-and-Workspaces-in-the-RStudio-IDE

Comment: @r2evans a screenshot is provided with the directory path (ending with " data" folder ) appearing in the console pane, even when using the setwd command, it executes for just one chunk and then the program sets back to the wrong default folder ( analysis ), please let me know if it is still confusing or unclear

Comment: @Phil but it it is clear in the provided screenshot, the console's directory is set to the path ending with the " Data " folder, while the error indicates that the program is looking for the csv file in a path ending with the " Analysis " folder, which is the wrong path therefore the error comes up

Comment: admo7000, okay, sorry, I don't use the RStudio IDE so I was not aware that that is a clear signal to where you are currently working.

Comment: @admo7000 Like I said, the path to your console would NOT be the path that your Rmd file uses when it gets knit, it uses the path in which your Rmd file is located. Create an Rmd file in the same location of your current Rmd file, and include within it a code chunk with `getwd()`. What does it show?